Change of basis for efficient distance computation?
Is there a computationally efficient method to compute distance between points and a line?
Note: the line is predefined; this is not a hyper-parameter to tune.
I know that the shortest path from a point to line A is a perpendicular line B, intersecting the point.
Of interest to me is computing the length of line B (from line A to the point) for hundreds of thousands of points.
Is this as simple as change of basis to line A as x and line B as y then extracting y?
If possible, Python is preferred.

Generally, a family of parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^n$ is determined by a unit vector $\mathbf v;$ the hyperplanes are each solutions of the equation $\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf v = c$ for some scalar $c.$  The distance between two such hyperplanes determined by $c_1$ and $c_2$ is $|c_2 - c_1|.$ Thus, the distance between a point $\mathbf y$ and one of these hyperplanes is $\mathbf y \cdot \mathbf v - c.$ That's as simple and efficient as it gets.  By prolonging $\mathbf v$ to an orthogonal basis you can characterize this as taking the $\mathbf v$ coefficient of $\mathbf y$ in that basis.

Yes, you can compute this distance using some simple calculations. If your line is characterized by
$$A: y = ax + b$$
and you have the points $(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n$, the distance to the line is given by
$$
\frac{|x_i \cdot a - y_i + b|}{\sqrt{a^2 + 1}}.
$$
See Wikipedia for a more general treatment (https://w.wiki/A6Qb).
In Python, this can be done using elementary and fast calculations (see the toy example below).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define points
points = np.array([[1, 2], 
                   [3, 2], 
                   [2, 3],
                   [4, 6]])

# Make line
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.01)
a = 0.5
b = 3
y =  a*x + b

# Show line and points in plot
plt.plot(x, y)
#> [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x20eb2f47770>]
plt.scatter(points[:,0],
            points[:,1])
#> <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x20e8bbd9220>
plt.show()



# Create vector with line coefficients
line = np.array([[a], [-1]])

d = np.abs(np.matmul(points, line) + b) / np.sqrt(0.5**2 + 1)
#> array([[1.34164079], [2.23606798], [0.89442719], [0.89442719]])
```

